# Where in the file system is my shared folder? (AKA: Where is /Volume, and Why Can't I Open It in Finder?)

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, filesystem

I want to run a `bash` script periodically to track the size of a shared drive on my network. The command that produces the data I want is `du -sh`. I have created a `Login item` to mount the shared drive when I login using `System Preferences`. I mount the drive as follows:

```
cifs://raspberrypi3b.local/passport2tb/data_lib
```

I have tried numerous variations for specifying the folder location for `du`, but none of them work properly. I get the following error message:

> du: //raspberrypi3b.local/passport2tb/data_lib: **No such file or directory**

It seems there is no folder path specification that `du` (or `bash`) can find. Yet, I know the share is mounted. I can get the stats using `File`, `Get Info` in Finder  (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>).

Where in the file system is my shared folder?

Comment: You might find the `df` command useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you are looking for is under `/Volumes` in your file system. `/Volumes` is sometimes called a ***hidden*** file in MacOS parlance.

#### Using Finder with *Hidden Files*:

There are at least two ways to expose *hidden files* in Finder:

1. Use the Finder menu to navigate to arbitrary folders:  ***Go, Go to Folder...***, (ALTERNATIVELY: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>), and then enter `/Volumes` in the text box. Of course this method requires that you know the name of the file/directory you're looking for, but once that's known this will get you there.
2. If you're running macos Sierra (or later), you can view ***all*** hidden files/folders in Finder like so: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (shift-command-period). Repeating this sequence will hide the *hidden folders* again.

*Note: To see `/Volumes` using the 2nd method, you must* ***position Finder at the proper place in the file system***; *i.e. at the `Macintosh HD` level (selected from Finder's sidebar if you have it enabled!).*

Once Finder has listed the *hidden file/folder* of interest, use the menu (***File, Get Info***) or shortcut (<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) to yield the *info* window with lots of handy information.

At this point, your questions re. Finder and *hidden files* have hopefully been answered. Now let's move on to the rest of your question re. how to display usage stats from the command line:

#### *Hidden Files* from the Command Line:

Open a terminal window (`bash` is the default macos shell). Just like every (?) other *nix system in the universe, the file system root is simply known as `/`. So, let's see what's in `/`:

```
$ ls -l /
total 13
drwxrwxr-x+ 80 root  admin  2560 Mar 17 18:42 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+ 64 root  wheel  2048 Feb  4 01:43 Library
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel    64 Feb  4 01:39 Network
drwxr-xr-x@  5 root  wheel   160 Sep 21 05:05 System
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  admin   224 Feb  4 01:39 Users
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   128 Mar 17 22:48 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@ 37 root  wheel  1184 Feb  8 02:57 bin
drwxrwxr-t   2 root  admin    64 Feb  4 01:39 cores
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  4512 Mar 17 12:17 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Feb  4 01:37 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 Mar 17 22:10 home
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   313 Aug 18  2018 installer.failurerequests
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 Mar 17 22:10 net
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96 Sep 26  2016 opt
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   192 Feb  4 01:39 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 64 root  wheel  2048 Feb  8 02:57 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Feb  4 01:37 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 root  wheel   320 Feb  4 01:44 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Feb  4 01:38 var -> private/var
$
```

Listed here are all of your files and folders, including links, and the *hidden files*, including `/Volumes`. If this makes you wonder about the conventional wisdom (or current practice) re. "ease of use" for Graphical User Interfaces (GUI), then you are on the right track :) But I digress...

Now, take a look to verify that your mounted shares are listed under `/Volume`. In your case, assuming your raspberrypi share is the only one mounted, you'll see something similar to this:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes
total 32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root    wheel      1 Mar 17 12:17 Macintosh HD -> /
d--x--x--x+ 2 macusr  wheel     64 Mar 17 12:18 passport2tb
drwx------  1 macusr  staff  16384 Mar  4 23:56 passport2tb-1
$
```

The first line is a *link* showing the mapping from the `Macintosh HD` to the file system root `/`. The second line will show your mounted network drive, but note the permissions - you won't be able to use this one. It's apparently an *artifact*. I don't know why it's there other than to set the `executable` permission bit for the folder; perhaps someone else can offer an explanation? At any rate, while we needn't be overly concerned about ***why*** it's there, automating this task will require that we identify the ***correct*** share name.

#### Automating the process via `bash` script:

The ***correct*** share name can be found as follows:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes | grep drwx | head -1 | awk '{print $9}'
drwx------  1 macusr  staff  16384 Mar  4 23:56 passport2tb-1 
passport2tb-1
$
```

To recap: `grep` will filter the output of `ls -l` to get the actual share (instead of the artifact), `head -1` will filter duplicates (which may show up as `passport2tb-2`, etc) and `awk '{print $9}'` will get the 9th field in the string which is the share name. If you have other shares mounted in `/Volumes`, simply add another `grep` stage to get the one(s) you're interested in.

Knowing the location of your mounted share will allow you to successfully execute the `du` command to **d**isplay the **u**sage statistics of any folder in the mounted share; for example:

```
$ du -sh /Volumes/passport2tb-1/data_lib
 75G    /Volumes/passport2tb-1/data_lib 
$
```

In this case, the folder `data_lib` folder contains 75GB of data... and this may take a few minutes to tally, even on a fast network.

Some command line gymnastics that might be useful:

- If you don't want/need the path information in `du`, use `awk` to strip it:

```
$ du -sh /Volumes/passport2tb-1/data_lib | awk '{print $1}'
75G
$
```

- And if you don't want the "G":

```
$ du -sh /Volumes/passport2tb-1/data_lib | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d "G" -f 1 
75
$
```

To wrap this up in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHRNM=$(ls -l /Volumes | grep drwx | head -1 | awk '{print $9}')
SIZE=$(du -sh /Volumes/$SHRNM/data_lib | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d "G" -f 1) 
echo $SIZE
```

***Finally: Save it, name it, make it executable, and add it to your `crontab` to be executed periodically.***

This answer has gotten long-winded, so I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: To "There's no other easy way to find this in Finder", well what about **⇧⌘.** (Shift-Command-Period) it toggles hidden files/folder in Finder since macOS Sierra.

Comment: @user3439894: Many thanks... it's amazing what one learns by posting an answer :) I'll edit my post now.

Comment: I’ll see if I can find a decent crontab answer to link to, thanks for being patient on some other threads.

Comment: @bmike: I must be losing it... I don't even remember posting this :)